# Display total number of comments related to each object in a list view

Tags: python, django

I have a view which displays all my posts. Post has `ForeignKey` relation with `comment`.I want to be able to display the total number of `comments` related to each post in a `Listview`. Like on facebook feedback one can see the total number of `comments` on each post display on user activity feed .

Model. py

```
class Post(models.Model):
   name=models.CharField(max_length=230,null=True)
   text=models.TextArea(null=True)


class Comments(models.Model):
   comment=models.TextArea(null=True)
   post=models.ForeignKey(Post,related_name="post",null=True,on_delete=model.CASCADE)
```

View.py

```
def PostListView(request):
#getting  all post objects 
    allpost=Post.objects.all()
#getting all comments 
    allcomments=Comments.objects.all()
    template_name="post.html"
    context={'allpost':allpost,'allcomments':allcomments}
    return render(request,template_name,context)

 def PostDetail(request,slug):
     postinstance=get_object_or_404(Post,slug)
     #getting comments for this post
     comments_for_post=Comments.objects.all().filter(post=postinstance)
     #get the total count for comments for post
     commentcount=comments_for_post.count()
```

In `Listview` I want to be able to display the total number of `comments` related for each `post`. In `Listview` template I want something like this:

```
{% for post in allpost %}
    {{post.name}}
    #get total number of comments for each post
    {{commentcount}}
{% endfor %}
```

Note I have no problem displaying the total number of comments for a post in DetailView . Please i need help in handling this query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to write any queryset. This can be achieved in your template:

```
# for big numbers
{% load humanize %}

{% for post in allpost %}
    {{post.name}}
    #get total number of comments for each post
    {{post.post.count|intword}}
{% endfor %}
```

=======

Optional but recommended:
Change the related_name in your Comment model as such:

```
class Comments(models.Model):
   comment=models.TextArea(null=True)
   post=models.ForeignKey(Post,related_name="comments",null=True,on_delete=model.CASCADE)
```

Then in the template:

```
# for big numbers
{% load humanize %}

{% for post in allpost %}
    {{post.name}}
    #get total number of comments for each post
    {{post.comments.count|intword}}
{% endfor %}
```

Edit: For formating big numbers, add 'django.contrib.humanize' to your INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: alright this seems to work . Lets say i have my comment count is greater than 1000 . How can i display the value 1k comments instead of displaying 1000comments .

Comment: @ebong I have updated my answer to format big numbers.

Comment: Also, use .count instead of .all|length for better performance as shown in the updated answer above.

Comment: it starts from 1million . But i tried this in my template  .{% if  post.comments.count >= 1000 %}  {{ post.comment.count}}k comments    {% else %}  {{post.comments.count}} comments {% endif %}  .But this does not seem to work , since it seems like  post.comment.count >= 1000 is not verifying

Comment: @ebong You can write a custom template filter to achieve that. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/

Answer (score 0):

You should use an annotation on your Post query.

```
from django.db.models import Count
allpost = Post.objects.all().annotate(commentcount=Count('post'))
```

Now you can do `{{ post.commentcount }}` in your template.

Note, the `related_name` on your FK to Post makes no sense, the `related_name` points from Post to Comments so should be called `comments`. Even better, leave it as the default, which would be `comment_set`.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is "group by" SQL equivalent.

```
from django.db.models import Count
Post.objects.values('post').annotate(dcount=Count('post'))
```

By the way, in your Comment class, the convention is to code :

```
   post=models.ForeignKey(Post,related_name="comments",null=True,on_delete=model.CASCADE)
```

instead of :

```
   post=models.ForeignKey(Post,related_name="post",null=True,on_delete=model.CASCADE)
```

Comment: How to display the count in template?